# How to apply 2 different condition in a single line python pandas code?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

According to the following table:

```
FamilyVsWWTotal = pd.DataFrame({'date':['2011-4-3','2011-3-5','2011-4-3','2011-5-7'], 'Country':['USA','CAN','USA','MEX'],'Revenues':[1200,1800,1000,800],'Customer':['Exxon','Google','Google','Microsoft']})

FamilyVsWWTotal = FamilyVsWWTotal.loc[FamilyVsWWTotal['Customer'] == 'Google']
FamilyVsWWTotal['total1'] = FamilyVsWWTotal.groupby(['date','Country'])['Revenues']\
                                           .transform('sum')
```

FamilyVsWWTotal['total1'] is a new column created. So, how to combine the code above in a single line codes?

Comment: Regardless of the answer, you would end up with a barely understandable line of code. Why do you want to combine the two lines?

Comment: because if i using the two line code above, it will move out the row which the Customer is not equal to Google

Comment: I plan to combine it because i wish to maintain the row which are not Google

Comment: It is not the problem with one or two statements. It is a problem with your code design. What must be the value of FamilyVsWWTotal['total1'] for the non-Google customers?

Comment: For the non- Google it will remain nan at total1

Comment: You need to post your data as a Python expression. To help you, we would need to retype the dataframe. I can't imagine anyone willing to do that.

Comment: @DYZ Done... enjoy.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Being so helpful, you could have probably answered the question, too, no? :)

Comment: @DYZ Indeed, I was planning to anyway :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need filter first and then add output to filtered column too:

```
m = FamilyVsWWTotal['Customer'] == 'Google'

FamilyVsWWTotal.loc[m, 'total1']=FamilyVsWWTotal[m].groupby(['date','Country'])['Revenues']\
                                                   .transform('sum')

print (FamilyVsWWTotal)
  Country   Customer  Revenues      date  total1
0     USA      Exxon      1200  2011-4-3     NaN
1     CAN     Google      1800  2011-3-5  1800.0
2     USA     Google      1000  2011-4-3  1000.0
3     MEX  Microsoft       800  2011-5-7     NaN
```

And for one row solution:

```
FamilyVsWWTotal.loc[FamilyVsWWTotal['Customer'] == 'Google', 'total1'] = \
FamilyVsWWTotal[FamilyVsWWTotal['Customer']=='Google'].groupby(['date','Country'])['Revenues']\
                                                      .transform('sum')

print (FamilyVsWWTotal)
  Country   Customer  Revenues      date  total1
0     USA      Exxon      1200  2011-4-3     NaN
1     CAN     Google      1800  2011-3-5  1800.0
2     USA     Google      1000  2011-4-3  1000.0
3     MEX  Microsoft       800  2011-5-7     NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate an inset and paste it into the original dataframe. Clumsy, but different.

```
rows = FamilyVsWWTotal['Customer'] == 'Google'
inset = FamilyVsWWTotal[rows].groupby(['date', 'Country'])['Revenues'].sum()
FamilyVsWWTotal.set_index(['date', 'Country'], inplace=True)
rows = FamilyVsWWTotal['Customer'] == 'Google'
FamilyVsWWTotal.loc[rows,'total1'] = inset
FamilyVsWWTotal.reset_index(inplace = True)

#       date Country   Customer  Revenues  total1
#0  2011-4-3     USA      Exxon      1200     NaN
#1  2011-3-5     CAN     Google      1800  1800.0
#2  2011-4-3     USA     Google      1000  1000.0
#3  2011-5-7     MEX  Microsoft       800     NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

```
FamilyVsWWTotal.assign(total1=FamilyVsWWTotal[FamilyVsWWTotal.Customer.eq('Google')].groupby(['date', 'Country']).Revenues.transform('sum'))

  Country   Customer  Revenues      date  total1
0     USA      Exxon      1200  2011-4-3     NaN
1     CAN     Google      1800  2011-3-5  1800.0
2     USA     Google      1000  2011-4-3  1000.0
3     MEX  Microsoft       800  2011-5-7     NaN
```

---

Same thing but breaking the line up

```
FamilyVsWWTotal.assign(
    total1=FamilyVsWWTotal[FamilyVsWWTotal.Customer.eq('Google')].groupby(
        ['date', 'Country']
    ).Revenues.transform('sum')
)

  Country   Customer  Revenues      date  total1
0     USA      Exxon      1200  2011-4-3     NaN
1     CAN     Google      1800  2011-3-5  1800.0
2     USA     Google      1000  2011-4-3  1000.0
3     MEX  Microsoft       800  2011-5-7     NaN
```